# Postgres table size is not growing after adding row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I couldn't see any growth in table size when I added a row in the relevant table. I see the same memory space even after adding 5 rows. Could anyone please help me and explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by `same memory space`? Do you mean `same disk space`? You could also provide the table's DDL and the DML of your INSERTs!

Comment: I bet you have a TEXT column in your table? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL tables are stored in 8kB blocks. A new row will be added to the first best block that has enough free space. Only if there is no block with free space, the table will be extended.

Keep inserting more rows, and eventually the table will grow.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270602/why-is-the-database-size-larger-than-sum-of-table-sizes) and would be interested in your opinion - I just hope I haven't made any errors!